# How can stop show notification when chat activity is already opened using firebase in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to stop show notification when chat activity is already opened.

Comment: You have to manage with flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save current user Id globally for which chatActivity is open in onCreate() method of ChatActivity and reset in onDestroy() method.  When you received notification then check if userId is already set and notification received for userId for which chat is going on, then don't display notification , else display notification.

Declare globally chatUserId;

```
public static int chatUserId=-1;
```

onCreate() method of ChatActivity

```
chatUserId= receiverId;
```

onDestroy() method of ChatActivity

```
chatUserId = -1;
```

When you received notification:

```
if(receivedUserID==chatUserId){
{
//Don't display notification
}else{
//display notification
}
```

Comment: This will work for either One to One chat or either Group Chat. Will not working for both. So just update your answer with group chat also thanks :).